# Alternative to $getField for MongoDB v4.4 aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using Atlas App Services which only supports MongoDB v4.4 and doesn't include `$getField` as an aggregation operator. I need to access a field of an object returned by an expression, and feel this must be possible without `$getField`, but can't figure out the syntax.

Simply, if I have an `<expression>`, what is the alternative to:

```
$getField: {
    field: "myFieldName",
    input: <expression>
}
```

The documentation implies `$getField` is only needed for unusual field names, beginning with a `.` or `$`.

A more complete example of the use case I need is below, where I want `isOwner` to be set to a boolean:

```
// Part of a $set in an aggregation
{ "isOwner" : {"$in" : [
    userId,
    {$getField: {
        field: "ownerIds",
        input: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$tasks", {
            $indexOfArray: [
                { $map: { input: "$tasks", as: "task", in: "$$task._id" }},
                "$$myId"
            ]
        }]}

    }}
]}}
```

There's a bit going on here, but my main question is how can I achieve the same without `$getField`. I may also be over-complicating the inner part that extracts a particular *task* from within an array of *tasks* by matching an Id - so glad of any comments on that too!

Comment: Hi. I think you can use `$let`, `$filter`, `$reduce`, etc. Can you please share some sample data and expected result? You can use https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: Check your mails. MongoDB version 4.4 will going to be end-of-life in one week. Your MongoDB should be upgraded very soon.

Comment: Please provide some sample data, I don't think you need `$getField` at all. In your example it might be simply `{ isOwner: {$in: [userId, "$ownerIds._id"] } }`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, and thanks to Tom (accepted answer) for providing [sample data](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2xt42_fzR3f). @WernfriedDomscheit, MongoDB support tell me this is not the case for Atlas App Services, and that there is no timeline for upgrading aggregation support beyond v4.4. Apparently this is because the existing rules engine for Role Based Authentication of non-system users only support v4.4. Which is a pity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "clean" way to do this, the approach I use is to convert the object to an array, filter it to the key I want and then extract the value, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "isOwner": {
        "$in": [
          userId,
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              {
                $map: {
                  input: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: {
                        "$objectToArray": {
                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                            "$tasks",
                            {
                                $indexOfArray: [
                                    { $map: { input: "$tasks", as: "task", in: "$$task._id" }},
                                    "$$myId"
                                ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      cond: {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this.k",
                          "ownerIds"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  in: "$$this.v"
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2xt42_fzR3f)

Comment: Thanks @tom-slabbaert, and thanks for making the working example. I'll use that work around, but it's strange it took until v5.0 for MongoDB to provide a nicer solution.

Comment: Yes.. some of my production DB's are still on 4.4 and this feature is something that you really feel is missing when you need it as the work around is not elegant.